# Find ObjectId _id but Schema has defined _id as String

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Previously I didn't declare the `_id` in my Schema, so each new submission naturally will have MongoDB generated `ObjectId` as it's `_id`. However, the requirements have changed and now `_id` is declared as `String` as below.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MySchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
    },
    schoolID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'School'
    },
    points: {
        type: Number
    },
});
MySchema.index({ schoolID : 1})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Submission', MySchema);
```

However, now I cannot find my previously inserted documents using `_id` at all. I tried

```
var submissionId = "60654319a8062f684ac8fde4"
Submission.findOne({ _id: mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(submissionId ) })
Submission.findOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(submissionId ) })
Submission.findOne({ _id: mongoose.ObjectId(submissionId ) })
```

but it will always return `null`. So when I use `var mongoose = require('mongoose').set('debug', true);` to check, it will display below; that all my queries above will still find using `String`, and not `ObjectId`

```
Mongoose: submission.findOne({ _id: '60654319a8062f684ac8fde4' }, { projection: {} })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem - `_id: { type: String,},` mongoose will cast the value before making a query to the database, so in your case, it will always be a string.

#### Option -1

Convert your old objectId's to String as you're planning to use String `_id` so it's better to keep it consistent.

Run these commands from the shell, Robomongo

This will add records with strings `_id` for existing `ObjectId` records.

```
db.collection.find({}).toArray() // loop all records
    .forEach(function (c) {
        if (typeof c._id !== 'string') { // check _id is not string
            c._id = c._id.str; db.collection.save(c); // create new record with _id as string value
        }
    });
```

Delete records with `ObjectId`

```
db.collection.remove({ _id: { $type: 'objectId' } })
```

---

#### Option -2

Add Mongoose custom types.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html

```
class StringOrObjectId extends mongoose.SchemaType {
  constructor(key, options) {
    super(key, options, 'StringOrObjectId');
  }

  convertToObjectId(v) {
    const checkForHexRegExp = new RegExp("^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$");
    let _val;
    try {
      if (checkForHexRegExp.test(v)) {
        _val = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(v);
        return _val;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  convertToString(v) {
    let _val = v;
    try {
      if(_.isString(_val)) return _val;
      if(_.isNumber(_val)) return _.toString(_val);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  cast(val) {
    const objectIdVal = this.convertToObjectId(val);
    if (objectIdVal) return objectIdVal;

    const stringVal = this.convertToString(val)
    if (stringVal) return stringVal;

    throw new Error('StringOrObjectId: ' + val +
        ' Nor string nor ObjectId');
  }
}

mongoose.Schema.Types.StringOrObjectId = StringOrObjectId;
```

---

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: StringOrObjectId, // custom type here
    },
    schoolID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'School'
    },
    points: {
        type: Number
    },
});
```

---

Query

```
Submission.findOne({ _id: submissionId }); // it will cast ObjectId or String or throw error
```

---

Drawbacks

- If your _id type string is `60516ae1ef682d2804a2fa72` is like valid `ObjectId` it will convert to `ObjectId` which will not match the record.

Note - It's a rough class `StringOrObjectId` add proper checks and test properly.

---

#### Option -3

Easy way - Use `mongoose.Mixed`
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-Mixed

```
cont MySchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: mongoose.Mixed,
    },
    schoolID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'School'
    },
    points: {
        type: Number
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no straight way to handle this situation in mongoose,

Mongoose casts the filter to match the model's schema before the command is sent. See [query casting tutorial](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/query_casting.html) for more information on how Mongoose casts filter.

You can try [custom schema types](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html),

```
class StrOrObjId extends mongoose.SchemaType {
    constructor(key, options) {
        super(key, options, 'StrOrObjId');
    }
    cast(val) {
        if (typeof val !== 'string' && !mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(val)) {
            throw new Error('StrOrObjId: ' + val + ' must be a String or ObjectId');
        }
        return val;
    }
}
// Don't forget to add `StrOrObjId` to the type registry
mongoose.Schema.Types.StrOrObjId = StrOrObjId;
```

Than use that type in `_id` field,

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: StrOrObjId,
    },
    schoolID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'School'
    },
    points: {
        type: Number
    }
});
```

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar thanks same to yours good solutions and explanation, i travelled whole mongoose but no way to manage this without custom type or mixed types.

Comment: Your solution allows me to solve the problem of finding a document by _id, but unfortunately now when I tried to save a document by giving a string id, it will return the error ` _id: Cast to Object failed for value "a6f9206987189042dbe97b7e6a50588aa589615bf9ea0753f2d0c2b48c0bb6be" at path "_id"` . `a6f9206987189042dbe97b7e6a50588aa589615bf9ea0753f2d0c2b48c0bb6be` is the String id

Comment: oh so sorry, you can try `mongoose.Mixed` type it will work, as per answer by tushar.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for trying to help though. But can you explain why your solution fails when trying to save a doc? From the surface, it looks like a very plausible solution. And by right, Mongoose should allow us to save both data type.

Comment: @imin i think they have no support of multiple types separated by or operator, that is why they have launched custom schema types function and `mongoose.Mixed` types. i have added custom schema type for both String and ObjectId types, it will help others as well.

Comment: @turivishal Yes buddy I also looked in documentation, but only `mongoose.Mixed` .